# Как удалить элемент из master ветки репозитория?

Tags: git, github

Добрый день уважаемые, подскажите, пожалуйста, какие команды нужно выполнить чтобы удалить файл из главной ветки.
Допустим, я случайно в git добавил файл `style/mywork.scss` . Что мне необходимо выполнить в окне `gitBash` чтобы удалить его, без последующего отображения на github'e ?
И ещё вопрос по данной же теме. В `.gitignore` я добавил запись для файла `.style/.scss` Но он всё равно добавился в git, в чём ошибка ?

Comment: Если файл уже тречится, `.gitignore` не поможет

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Чтобы удалить файл из репозитория необходимо сделать следующее:

1. Во первых, убедиться что Вы на ветке `master`:

   ```
   git branch
   ```

   *Она будет выделена зелёным и звёздочкой.*
2. Если Вы не на нужной ветке, то переключиться на неё:

   ```
   git checkout master
   ```
3. Затем необходимо удалить файл.
   Для этого есть два варианта, можно воспользоваться любым:

   - можно удалить Git-командой:

     ```
     git rm <путь_к_удалённому_файлу>
     ```
   - либо просто удалить файл с диска (можете просто через проводник) и добавить изменение в индекс следующей командой:

     ```
     git add <путь_к_удалённому_файлу>
     ```

   *После выполнения одного из двух вариантов файл будет удалён, а изменения в индексе.*
4. Фиксируем изменения:

   ```
   git commit -m "удалил файл <название_файла>"
   ```

   *Сообщение можно другое, это как пример.*
5. Далее необходимо отправить Ваши изменения на удалённую ветку (на github).
   Это можно сделать так:

   ```
   git push
   ```

   либо так:

   ```
   git push origin master
   ```

**.gitignore**

Файл `.gitignore` необходимо добавлять в репозиторий в самом начале. Если вдруг Вы закомитили какие-то файлы, а потом добавили их в `.gitignore`, то файлы, которые уже под присмотром Git-а не будут удалены, но новые файлы, подподающие под правила из `.gitignore`, добавляться не будут.

Comment: лучше удалить файл через `git rm <имя-файла>` - она и файл удалит, и сделает для него add. После этого можно сразу коммитить. `git add .` может добавить "лишнего".

Comment: @KoVadim, заменил `git add .` на `git add <путь_к_удалённому_файлу>`. Думаю, так проблем не будет, а про `git rm` хорошее замечание, если не против, то могу к ответу добавить :)

Comment: конечно дополняйте.

Answer (score 4):

Способ, приведённый в [сообщении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/622731/183314) Umed'а, удалит файл в текущем состоянии репозитория, но оставит всё содержимое файла в истории. Что может быть нежелательно, если нечаянно зафиксировали файл с паролями / ключами / токенами.

Удалить такой файл можно командой

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f имя_файла' master
```

**Внимание!** Эта команда именит хеши всех коммитов, в которых был указанный файл, а также всех более поздних коммитов. Будьте аккуратны при последующей отправке изменений на сервер. Возможно, для вас будет полезна опция `--force` команды *push*.

Подробнее см. [Pro Git: Исправление истории](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8#_removing_file_every_commit) и [git-filter-branch(1)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_examples)

P.S.: отменить действие команды можно, например, так

```
git checkout -B master refs/original/refs/heads/master
```

Comment: **Внимание!** Если вы один раз засветили свои пароли, ключи или токены - они могут быть уже кем-то найдены и записаны. Вместо `filter-branch` будет правильнее немедленно поменять их на новые, сделав старые недействительными.

Comment: И, если вы используете облако от Amazon - посмотрите на общий список ключей доступа, виртуальных машин и прочее. Возможно, на ваши деньги уже работает ферма биткоин-майнеров. Существуют боты, которые постоянно следят за появлением в открытом доступе на гитхабе ключей от Amazon.