# Вопрос по возвращению к старым коммитам

Tags: git, github

Здравствуйте,  я сначала разработки проекта совершил ошибку , не добавил .gitignore  файлы чтобы они в дальнейшем не пушились на github, осознав только сейчас ошибку я добавил файлы которые не нужно было включать в коммит, но дело в том, что коммиты которые я делал раньше эти файлы ненужные остались на своём месте, можно как то вернутся к раннему коммиту и там сделать что то типа git rm -r --cached .?? Мне это важно потому что файлов настолько много, что страничка с коммитом на гитхабе  лагает. Делаю проект на Asp.Net Mvc в Visual Studio. К самому новому коммиту я сделал следующее

```
git rm -r --cached .

git add .
Commit it:

git commit -m ".gitignore is now working"
```

оно показало что удалило много файлов, но в старых коммитах эти файлы на месте

Comment: Почитайте ответ - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431521/248502. Там есть то, что вам нужно

Comment: @Egor спасибо, но я немного еще путаюсь , это вообще возможно реализовать то что я написал в своём вопросе? я там почитал и не вьезжаю что именно мне нужно в данном случае сделать

Comment: @alexanderbarakin пользуюсь один, пока что работаю только с maste, для начала хочу вернуться  хотя бы к одному коммиту и оттуда удалить файлы, ну а потом и полностью переписать историю чтобы со всех старых коммитов удалить файлы

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как удалить элемент из master ветки репозитория?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/622709/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7-master-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin с того ответа цитирую : "Файл .gitignore необходимо добавлять в репозиторий в самом начале. Если вдруг Вы закомитили какие-то файлы, а потом добавили их в .gitignore, то файлы, которые уже под присмотром Git-а не будут удалены" , ТАм также писали о git rm , он же удалит файлы с моего каталога на диске самом также...

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ага , вижу , эта команда git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f имя_файла' master , но если у меня много файлов .в gitgnore как тогда правильно записать эту комманду? Извините, я просто боюсь наделать сейчас в своём же репозитории беды

Comment: @M-Misha-M в качестве «клона» можно просто копировать папку на своей рабочей машине куда-нибудь.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin После описаных выше команд ,  я попробовал на тестовом проекте несколько комманд, например эту git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filename' master, потом git push origin master --force и  получил такой результат "Rewrite 3e..... 4/4. WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged".Оно как бы переписало только последний коммит , я смотрел через git log, посмотрел в репозитории файл который указал, а он так и остался в самом первом коммите

Comment: @alexanderbarakin спасибо команда  git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f passwords.txt' HEAD помогла, оно удалило файл со всех коммитов вроде бы, но у меня 2 вопроса: так что делать если файлов в .gitignore много? эта комманда я так понял git filter-branch --tree-filter "find * -type f -name '*~' -delete" HEAD. не сделает задуманое? и 2 вопрос: после того  как я написал команду мне гит сказал master branch and 'origin/master' have diverged , и дальше написало использовать git -pull , что вообще произошло? почему вывело данное сообщение? можете подсказать?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin p.s. Я после filter-branch использовал git push origin master -force

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58808/discussion-between-m-misha-m-and-alexander-barakin).

Comment: если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста с помощью соответствующей кнопки в правом верхнем углу страницы.

Answer (score 0):

В git есть ровно один способ "изменить" коммит - создать новый, похожий.

Для этого нужно в истории найти самый последний коммит, который не содержит того, что вам не нужно. Возможно, это окажется самый первый коммит.

Затем в интерактивном режиме сделать rebase всех более поздних коммитов, на этот чистый, просматривая каждый и внося соответствующие правки.

Затем заменить ветку master на новую, где все хорошо. Последнее действие потенциально опасно, т.к. старая ветка master исчезнет, а значит и все коммиты, которые есть только в ней.

Каждое из действий описано в справке.